# Is the Zeta Draconis's thraddash-guarding battle... endless?

Tags: star-control-2

I'm trying to get some sort of sacred relic from a certain planet within the star system Zeta Draconis, which I found it guarded by a whole ton of thraddash ships.. and after some dialogue the thraddash "sent me into oblivion" (in other words, one shooting every ship they'd send).

So yeah, the problem isn't facing thraddash in battle, but the amount of them which were rounding the planet (from which I believe) they were almost 50 of them, and I've been one-shooting every single thraddash ship, but they keep coming and coming... I've been like 25 minutes doing the same thing over and over.

[image]

Does anyone know from a trivia or something, how many do I have to face? Or is it literally a ridiculous number intended to make me alt+f4 the game?

I'm playing The Ur-Quan Masters v0.7.0 if that means something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The homeworld fight is indeed endless, IIRC. What you need to do is kill enough  ships in hyperspace to impress the Thraddash with your skill. Then they'll offer you an alliance.

Alternatively, you can use the Caster to trick the Ilwrath into going to war with the Thraddash, which will wipe both of them out after a while.

Comment: On a side note: if the number of ships in the combat extends off of the screen, then there's an infinite number of ships.

Comment: Damn.. I thought it was still a fixed not-that-high number, considering that you can't go back to main menu once you start the fight, the only way out at that moment AFAIK is to Alt+F4.

Comment: Btw, the first option Iker mentioned, worked out for me.

Comment: You can also convince the Thraddash to go fight the Ur-Quan, leaving the planet unguarded.